# Azure DevOps Deployment shows InvalidRequestContent: Request content contains one or more instances of unsupported reference property names

Tags: azure, azure-functions, devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-deployment

We get an error on deploying our Logic-App with Azure DevOps.
I can't explain why this error occurs all at once.
Has anyone seen this error message before?

```
InvalidRequestContent:
Request content contains one or more instances of unsupported reference property names ($id, $ref, $values) creating ambiguity in paths 'properties.definition.actions.Parse_JSON.inputs.schema.properties.caseId.$ref,properties.definition.actions.Parse_JSON.inputs.schema.properties.integrationId.$ref'.
Please remove the use of reference property names and try again.
```

Our logic-app contains following JSON-Parse code. Apparently the variable "#/definitions/nonEmptyString" is defined twice.

```
"caseId": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/nonEmptyString",
    "type": "string"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue reproduced from my end and got expected results.

- **The issue is with $ref which is not supported by Azure logicapps as mentioned in error got**.
- Created logic app as shown below and the sample JSON-Parse code is taken as per your requirement

```
{
"caseId": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/nonEmptyString",
"type": "string"
  }
     }
```

[image]

- By taking $ref got the same error as shown below

**`Failed to save logic app parselp. Request content contains one or more instances of unsupported reference property names ($id, $ref, $values) creating ambiguity in paths 'properties.definition.actions.Parse_JSON.inputs.schema.caseId.$ref'. Please remove the use of reference property names and try again.`**

- Then **removed $ and taken ref in Parse Json** as shown and logic App saved successfully without that error and workflow ran successfully.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! I wonder if the condition "nonEmptyString" still works without the $.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by changing the following code

```
"definitions":{
   "nonEmptyString":{
      "minLength":1,
      "type":"string"
   }
},
"properties":{
   "caseId":{
      "$ref":"#/definitions/nonEmptyString",
      "type":"string"
}
```

to this code

```
"properties":{
   "caseId":{
      "minLength":1,
      "type":"string"
}
```

Maybe the problem was simply that my old solution defined "type": "string" twice. But I have not tested that yet.